# can't access to tomcat outside my own PC

Tags: tomcat

I have a problem with tomcat every thing works fine when I try to access to tomcat from my pc but when I try using mobile or an other PC from the same LAN I can't get any response 
here is my connector

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               address="0.0.0.0" />
```

I tried also without the attribute adress but it does not work also

Comment: What will happen if you remove the address attribute and try `http://<ip-adrress-from-your-pc:8080` ?

Comment: it works fine the only problem is when try to access from an other device 
and I have tested it, it pings correctly to my pc

Answer (score 0):

I solved it 
the problem was with the firewall not tomcat 
I just runned this command as an administrator

```
netsh firewall set opmode mode = disable
```